# indexing PDF's in Hibernate Search 3.3.0 Final does not work

Tags: java, hibernate, pdf, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a Problem with indexing PDF's and therefore Problems with the Full text -Search capabilities of Hibernate Search. I am trying to index around 3750 Objects. Each Object has several Fields including 2 Strings I want to index :

```
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "ANZEIGENAME")
private String anzeigeName;                     //  VARCHAR2(250),  
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "BESCHREIBUNG")
private String beschreibung;                //  VARCHAR2(512),
```

And also a byte[ ] field i want to index for Fulltext-Search on those PDF's

```
@Field(index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = FieldBridgeConverter.class)
@Lob
@Column(name = "PDFDATA")
private byte[] pdfData;     //  BLOB;
```

This is what my FieldBridge for the PDF's looks like

```
public class FieldBridgeConverter implements StringBridge {    
        public String objectToString(final Object object) {    
            byte[] file = (byte[]) object;   
            return file.toString();
        }   
}
```

The Problem now is that those 3750 Objects have a combined Size of 3.5 Gb.
So after persisting one after another my index Folder has a combined size of 1.5 mb for 3750 Objects. Seems a bit odd because according to http://lucene.apache.org/core/
Index-Files are ~20-30% of the size of the Text. So it should be at least around 500 mb.

This is my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="DlcHibernateDAO">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <jta-data-source>java:/DlcDS</jta-data-source>
    <!--    <class>servicepackage.DlcBO</class>-->
    <!--    <jta-data-source>java:/DownloadcenterDS</jta-data-source> -->
        <class>servicepackage.ClickBO</class>
        <class>servicepackage.DlcBO</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding"
                value="UTF-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
            <!-- JBoss 7 uses Hibernate 3 module -->
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
                value="org.hibernate.search.store.FSDirectoryProvider" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="C:/Temp/indexes" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't get any Exceptions and all the Objects are in my Database.I can't update the Version of Hibernate Search because I have to work with Hibernate 3.So where did I screw up?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the first step is to look at the index. Since you are using a file system directory and you are storing the indexed values, you can use something like Luke to inspect the index. Once you do that, I would not be surprised if you find a lot of gibberish. The problem is that you are passing a binary format (pdf) to Lucene. Lucene does not know how to handle pdf files. It only works with strings. If you want to index pdf, word, xml, etc you need some sort of converter program which will extract the indexable text from your file/data. Apache Tika is such a tool which can handle a lot of different binary data formats including pdf.

From Hibernate Search 4.2 there actually exists a built-in TikaBridge which could be used. However, you would need to upgrade. I think the TikaBridge code could probably be back-ported (using a custom bridge), but I'd rather go forward and upgrade Hibernate ORM and Search. Why can you not upgrade Hibernate? What holds you to Hibernate 3?

If you want to try a backport/custom bridge, have a look at the [TikaBridge](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/TikaBridge.java) source. It shows you the basic approach.

Comment: I cant upgrade because  my Company works with hibernate 3 at the Moment.
I have tried TikaBridge before . i didnt work either/ hasnt Change anything to the index

Comment: And also isnt my FieldBridge covering the string Problem? Or am i mistaken.